# Eslint combining naming conventions

Tags: regex, eslint, typescript-eslint

I want to combine `snake_case` and `PascalCase` naming conventions. So, declaring a `class` its name must match the following format **strictly**: `Pascal_Snake`, `Pascal_Snake_Pascal_Etc`, `OnlyPascal`, `Pascal`.

That's what I'm trying to do in my `esling.config`:

```js
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  {
      selector: "class",
      format: null,
      custom: {
          regex: "([A-Z]\\w*_?[A-Z]\\w+)|([A-Z]\\w*[A-Z]?\\w+)",
          match: true,
      },
  },
]
```

Unfortunately, this `regex` is not strict. What I want is:

1. After `_` there must be at least one capital letter always.
2. If you do not provide `_` — you must name classes according to `PascalCase` format.

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\w`  can match upper/lower case chars and `_`

You could match an optional underscore before matching an uppercase char A-Z in an optionally repeated group.

(Note to double escape the backslashes if that is required.)

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]*(?:_?[A-Z][a-z]*)*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k2DsVm/1)

If you don't want to match a single A or AA, you can repeat the lowercase chars 1+ times instead.

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?:_?[A-Z][a-z]+)*\b
```

Comment: How to make it possible to leave digits in the end like `SomethingSpeical1` or `Something_Special123` in the 1st regex? (`PascalCase` allows it)

Comment: @DenisRybkin You could either add them to the character class to allowed mixed chars a-z and digits `\b[A-Z][a-z0-9]*(?:_?[A-Z][a-z0-9]*)*\b` or add optional digits after the optional chars a-z like `\b[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*(?:_?[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*)*\b` See https://regex101.com/r/tY44V7/1